# Pre-populate contact information

Tags: kentico

If a person has previously filled out a contact us form on our website, the next time they visit that form I would like their information pre-populated. Using Kentico EMS and the form builder, how can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the contact informant via macros or custom macro methods and place it in the contact form default values (I would use an alternative form), but often you do not know if the user already exists unless they are logged in or enter the same email (which you would then need to add a client side trigger to Ajax an api once the email field is filled out, check for that contact in the api, return json of their info and populate the form).

to build the api you can either use the Kentico rest service or if you need more flexibility use the web part to api coupled with a repeater with custom query, adding the right where condition through macros.